# UIViewController subclass not being released after dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

So I've run into what appears to be a problem that has been solved time and time again here. Unfortunately, I'm at wits end, so I'll post and see if anybody can help.

As the title suggests, I've got a memory leak (unbounded memory growth). I can see in Instruments (Allocations) that my InspectionPageTableViewController object is being allocated, but never deallocated - there is a malloc, but no corresponding free. The trouble is, I can't see how this is happening. The entire history of the object looks like this (from the view controller being instantiated, to its dismissal):

[image]

The stack trace for this event looks like this:

[image]

The code for the method in question (in InspectionViewController) is this:

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(NSUInteger)page
{
    NSUInteger numberOfPages = self.titleView.numberOfPages;
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = page == numberOfPages;

    if (page >= numberOfPages)
    {
        return;
    }

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    InspectionPageTableViewController *controller = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
    {
        controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InspectionPageTableViewController"];
        [self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    }

    // Add page to controller
    controller.pageModel = [self.inspectionModel.pages objectAtIndex:page];

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(frame) * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;

        [self addChildViewController:controller];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
        [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
    [controller.tableView reloadData];
}
```

While InspectionViewController deallocates successfully, the InspectionPageTableViewController instantiated here with the line

```
controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InspectionPageTableViewController"];
```

... never does.

I've tried removing the InspectionPageTableViewController from it's superviews in this object, as well as removing it from any and all of the views it is otherwise added to in this object (although this seems pointless, since the calling object deallocates successfully anyway). Furthermore there are no occurrences of the string "InspectionPageTableViewController" outside of this class and the InspectionPageTableViewController class itself.

I'm suspicious of the UIStoryboard method -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: but I have seen several answers here on SO which say it returns an autoreleasing object. So this can't be the problem.

Can somebody give me a clue as to what's going on here? If there were more strong references to the object, surely I would be able to see the retain events in the history in Instruments?

Comment: That history dump was more than a little misleading... I didn't have 'Record reference counts' enabled. Looking at a more complete dump now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a couple of things wrong. I didn't have 'Record reference counts' enabled in Instruments, so I wasn't getting the full picture. The full picture looked like this:

[image]

And the call in the middle of all that, the tableView:viewForHeaderInSection retain, involved an object for which the InspectionPageTableViewController set itself as the delegate. This object's delegate property was, sadly, 'strong'. Once it was set to 'weak', the object deallocated automatically as expected. So, once again, one of the 'usual suspects'.

Answer (score 0):

Reading carefully what you wrote, I see two possible reasons:

2) You are using view controller containment wrongly. VC containment is notoriously tricky. You are probably not removing it from self.childViewControllers (using the right method call for this containment removal operation)

3) If you are adding a VC to a navigation controller, you should use push and pop, not containment.

Comment: After a lot of digging, it turns out I had a component in the VC which had a strong delegate property. And the VC set itself as delegate. So... one of the usual suspects. Thanks for reading and thanks for the reply though :)